# (Done) Reopen request: Can my company stop me from working overtime?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Can my company stop me from working overtime?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/135843/can-my-company-stop-me-from-working-overtime)

This question was just put on hold as "unclear what you're asking" - which I don't understand, given that the actual title is a very clear question, which is essentially repeated in the body of the text.

Comment: And why do you think it should stay open? Thre's a close reason saying ___"Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click here."___ which seems more appropriate - I agree, but nevertheless, I see no reason for re-opening.

Comment: **I voted to re-open**

Answer (score 1):

The question received enough votes and is open again now.